# How can i check whether any child of container div has an error class by using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Suppose the following HTML div container

```
<div id="container">
    <form>
        <div>
            <label class="error">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Age</label>
            <input type="text" name="age"/>
        </div> 
    </form>
</div>
```

How can i check whether any child of container div has an error class by using JQuery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#container .error").length
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').children( function(){
if( $(this).hasClass( 'error' ) )
{
//do something
}
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($("#container label.error").length == 0) {
  // none
} else {
  // at least one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started from the #container:

CODE

```
jQuery("#container").find("label").each(function (i) {
  if ( jQuery(this).hasClass("error") ) {
    //error exist
  }
});
```